# Eclipse valid targetplatform, but classes in plugins not resolving

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

Migrating from Kepler.2 IDE to Mar.2 IDE I needed to build a target file so I could still use the older plugins we depend on.

I managed to build a target file manually that satisfies all dependencies in the 30+ plugins in my project, just 10 unrelated errors. But I switched to the target definition dialog and it has done something that is not visible to me and instead of the 10 errors I had with 1 plugin suddenly I had over 54000 errors across my 30+ plugins. The classes not being resolved in the imports are all satisfied by the plugins in the targetplatform. I have tried restarting Eclipse, clean builds, reloading the target file, nothing now changes the high number of errors.

Any ideas on what could cause this. The target file lods and looks fine in the targetplatform dialog. locations and content tabs are displaying fine.

Here are the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="kepler" sequenceNumber="135">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.hsqldb.feature.group" version="2.2.8.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.apache.commons.logging.feature.group" version="1.1.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.apache.log4j.feature.group" version="1.2.16.201310261216"/>
<unit id="com.mysql.jdbc.feature.group" version="5.1.11.201310261216"/>
<unit id="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.feature.group" version="3.0.1301.201310261216"/>
<unit id="javax.persistence.feature.group" version="2.0.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="com.db4o.feature.group" version="7.4.155.v20120928-1733"/>
<unit id="org.dom4j.feature.group" version="1.6.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.postgresql.feature.group" version="9.0.0.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.hibernate.feature.group" version="4.1.1.201310261216"/>
<repository location="http://www.elver.org/eclipse/2.0.0/update"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.contribution.xref.feature.group" version="2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800"/>
<unit id="org.aspectj.feature.group" version="1.7.3.20130613144500-a"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.feature.group" version="2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group" version="2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/43/update"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.slf4j.log4j" version="1.7.2.v20130115-1340"/>
<unit id="org.w3c.dom.events" version="3.0.0.draft20060413_v201105210656"/>
<unit id="org.apache.commons.io" version="2.0.1.v201105210651"/>
<unit id="org.apache.commons.lang" version="2.6.0.v201205030909"/>
<unit id="org.junit" version="4.11.0.v201303080030"/>
<unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="1.3.0.v201303031735"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140114142710/repository/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.sdk.feature.group" version="2.0.1.v201508111358"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.feature.group" version="2.0.1.v201508111358"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.cdo.sdk.feature.group" version="2.0.1.v201508111358"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.cdo.feature.group" version="2.0.1.v201508111358"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/teneo/updates/2.0.0/interim/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy20.feature.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy23.feature.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy22.feature.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy21.feature.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<unit id="org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group" version="2.9.1.xx-201411061336-e43-RELEASE"/>
<repository location="http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.3"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug" version="3.8.0.v20130514-0841"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui" version="3.6.200.v20130514-0841"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui" version="3.9.2.v20131106-1600"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit" version="3.7.200.v20130514-0733"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core" version="3.7.200.v20130514-1154"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="3.9.1.v20140221-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140221-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.sdk.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201306071421"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.source.feature.group" version="2.1.3.201402040808"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.3.2.M20140221-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.eef.codegen.ecore-feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201301111054"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.9.1.v20140221-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.validation.sdk.feature.group" version="1.7.0.201306111341"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.ide.ui.source.feature.group" version="2.1.3.201402040808"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.sdk.plus.feature.feature.group" version="0.10.2.v20140217-1225"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.9.2.v20140203-1126"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group" version="1.2.2.v20140206-1358"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.birt.osgi.runtime.sdk.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140211-1400-795388UF5G6LKl-4mBu2LJ7GXD29"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group" version="0.10.2.v20140217-1225"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="3.9.1.201308190730"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140221-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140221-1852"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.birt.chart.cshelp.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140211-1400-5217w3125132202511"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.export.feature.feature.group" version="0.10.2.v20140217-1225"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.9.0.v20140221-1852"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.amalgam.discovery.feature.group" version="1.4.0.201308130745"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.xsd.sdk.feature.group" version="2.9.1.v20140203-1126"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.birt.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140211-1400-DPDKA5GixAoaudOsMil4K3C7KNz0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.datatools.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="1.11.2.v201309171554-7PAi7gFEpPZGKz-8iIz--X8NuUhz"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.net4j.sdk.feature.group" version="4.2.1.v20140218-1830"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.diffmerge.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="0.2.0.v20130523-0727"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="1.11.2.v201309171554-7I9v7XFE9JgQP0oJDSE2RI-mNjpc"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.eef.sdk-feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.201301111054"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.source.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140221-1852"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.tools.feature.group" version="0.10.2.v20140217-1225"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.oda.sdk.feature.group" version="1.2.0.v20140203-1126"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.birt.cshelp.feature.group" version="4.3.2.v20140211-1400-5217w3125132202511"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.transaction.sdk.feature.group" version="1.7.0.201306111400"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group" version="3.6.0.v20140117-1004"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.sdk.id" version="4.3.2.M20140221-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.ide.ui.feature.group" version="2.1.3.201402040808"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.5.2.v201401062113-7H7IFizDxumVu0K6bjdPjXRkoz0FiUYMnSyT9PL"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.feature.group" version="2.1.3.201402040808"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.graphiti.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="0.10.2.v20140217-1225"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.diagram.gmf.feature.group" version="2.1.3.201402040808"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.ant.launching" version="1.0.300.v20140203-1328"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation" version="1.5.0.v20130605-1748"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching" version="3.7.1.v20131218-1102"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.gef" version="3.9.0.201308190730"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="3.9.1.v20130725-1141"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="3.102.1.v20130827-2021"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.ui" version="3.105.0.v20130522-1122"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.draw2d" version="3.9.0.201308190730"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.cdo.feature.group" version="4.5.0.v20160320-0839"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.net4j.feature.group" version="4.5.0.v20160607-1254"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.net4j.db.feature.group" version="4.5.0.v20160607-1254"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.net4j.db.h2.feature.group" version="4.2.300.v20160301-1326"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.db.feature.group" version="4.4.0.v20160607-1254"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.feature.group" version="4.5.0.v20160607-1254"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/cdo/updates/integration/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

After years of using Eclipse I have never found the cause of these p2 related issues, this is not the only one I encounter. If you have a look at the PDE forum on the Eclipse forums you will see a very large number of questions unanswered, some of them mine. The problem above is intermittent, I have no idea what causes it. Currently it has 'gone away'.

One thing I noticed is how slow the resolution of the plugins is from the update site, literally walk away from the machine slow. The sites themselves respond in the browser quickly, I have a fast internet connection.

My advice to anyone is not to use the Target Editor, but use a text editor and carefully craft your target file. The Target Editor often ended up from one restart to the next going from all plugins resolved to none.